# Why appending a div using html and jquery variable has different outputs?

Tags: javascript, html, loops, append

Trying to solve a practice related to javaScript and JQuery, and have met an issue which I could not identify.

I created a variable to store a div, and tried to create multiple instances of it as follows:

> *(there is a logical mistake I have in inner loop related to the number of appended defineBox objects but this is something I am
>   working on separately,not related to this topic)*

```
 $("#wrapper").empty();
 var lineBox=document.createElement('div');

for(var i=0; i<size; i++){
  $('#wrapper').append('lineBox');
  for(var j=0; j<size; j++){
    $("#wrapper > div ").append(defineBox(boxSize));
  }
}
```

When the code is executed, it shows only one "lineBox" div in html document. defineBox is appended to the lineBox div.

When I use the following code instead, it displays "i" times of 'div' just as expected from the loop and each 'div' includes 'defineBox's.

```
for(var i=0; i<size; i++){
  $('#wrapper').append('<div></div>');
  for(var j=0; j<size; j++){
    $("#wrapper > div ").append(defineBox(boxSize));
  }
}
```

I thought creating a var with `document.createElement('div')` would have the same result as `'<div></div>'`. Where does the difference come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the jQuery's `.clone()` method. You're creating one instanced of the `div` in the dom.

```
$("#wrapper").empty();
var lineBox=document.createElement('div');
$('#wrapper').append(lineBox);
for(var i=0; i<size-1; i++){
  $('#wrapper').append(lineBox.clone());
  for(var j=0; j<size; j++){
    $("#wrapper > div ").append(defineBox(boxSize));
  }
}
```

Here is the documentation for the clone method of jQuery:
https://api.jquery.com/clone/

Comment: thank you for the tip, this method might help me for the "logical mistake" I mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Each time this expression called

`$('#wrapper').append('<div></div>');`

`jQuery` creates a new `div` element. In the first example you've shared, new `div` element created  just once with `var lineBox=document.createElement('div');`

Comment: spot on! Thank you for the explanation. I was wondering why my method "defineBox" (which is not included in the code part) works with this way and this loop didn't, I just noticed it.